# How to open oracle ORA file on DataGrip 2022 on windows 11?

Tags: oracle, datagrip

I have an `.ora` file that I want to open on `DataGrip` 2022.1.2 installed on windows 11.

I installed `Oracle 21c XE`, and went with ([Connect to Oracle with OCI](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/datagrip/how-to-connect-to-oracle-with-oci.html)).
Everything worked okay to the point of creating the `tnsnames.ora` file. But, I didn't understand the **alias** and the **address** I need to fill in, in order to open the .ora file.

What do I do next to open this file?

Edit:
In what folder do i paste the ora file? What do i write in HOST? What do I write in Service Name?

Answer (score 2):

`tnsnames.ora` is just a text file. You can create or open it with any text editor. As in the example tnsnames.ora file in your link, the content should look something like this (replace example values with your hostname or IP address, port, service_name, etc.):

```
MyTNSAlias =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = db.my.domain.com)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = my_service.my.domain.com)
    )
  )
```

The "alias" is the label `MyTNSAlias` on the left of the equals sign. It can be almost anything, but must be unique within the file and is not case sensitive.

The "address" is everything to the right of the equals sign:

```
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = db.my.domain.com)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = my_service.my.domain.com)
    )
  )
```

From the link you included:

> 1. In the directory that you created on Step 1, create the network directory. Inside the network directory, create the admin directory.
>    The overall path should look as follows:
>    ~/Oracle/instantclient_19_8/network/admin.
> 2. In the admin directory, create the tnsnames.ora file with the following structure:...

tnsnames.ora files can generally be found in the $ORACLE_HOME/network/admin directory. If Oracle 19c XE is installed, then there's probably already a tnsnames.ora file in that directory tree. If you're using Oracle Instant Client, then you'd need to copy the tnsnames.ora to *that* ORACLE_HOME directory tree.

For Oracle 21c XE connection, *see the documentation*: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/xeinl/connecting-oracle-database-xeinl.html

`HOST` is the DNS resolvable hostname or IP address of your database server (wherever you installed the database). You can check the database listener to see what address it is using with the `lsnrctl status` command, and list system IP addresses with the `ipconfig` (Windows) or `ifconfig` (Linux) commands. If it is on the same machine you want to connect from, you can also say `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` in your connection address. The default `PORT` for Oracle is always `1521`. The default `SERVICE_NAME` is `XE` for the container database (CDB) and `XEPDB1` for the pluggable database. For example:

```
xepdb1 =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = xepdb1)
    )
  )
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time and looking into this. I got that part, where to put the store.ora and what to write exactly in the address part i didn’t get. I’m on my machine and oracle XE is installed with the default settings. How to comprise the address on localhost?

Comment: How about `HOST=localhost` ?

Comment: I’m really sorry, I’m not being ungrateful, because I’m really am. But your answer is already explained in the documentation. The problem is “i cannot open the ora file”? In what folder to i put it? What is the complete Host name? What is the service name? If I come of as clueless it’s because I am clueless. I searched everywhere and cannot find an answer :(

Answer (score 2):

The DataGrid doc page "Step 3. Configuring ORA files﻿" told you to put the `tnsnames.ora` into `~/Oracle/instantclient_19_8/network/admin`.

The part `~/Oracle/instantclient_19_8` is called the Oracle Home, roughly means the installation location of the Oracle software. The default location of of `tnsnames.ora` is `%ORACLE_HOME%\network\admin` on Windows, and it should be something like `C:\app\oracle\product\21.1.0\xe` (according to convention of older XE release). The Oracle software installer should configure the environment variable `%ORACLE_HOME%` for you.

The DataGrid doc page also includes a sample TNS entry:

```
MyTNSAlias =
    (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = db.my.domain.com)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
    (SERVER = DEDICATED)
    (SERVICE_NAME = my_service.my.domain.com)
  )
)
```

You can put `HOST = localhost` or the actual hostname or the IP address. For XE, use `SERVICE_NAME = xe`.